# Creating a "zoom in" and "zoom out" driven by mouse scroll wheel within web pages

Tags: jquery, html, ruby-on-rails

I'm looking for a similar experience to autocad ... or solidworks

basically the content sizes  (maintaining aspect ratio) Xsize * Ysize

and magnifies particular areas

and I've included ruby / rails as my language of choice

Comment: Don't you get that for free? All browsers support ctrl+mouse wheel to zoom. Apple obviously uses command key.

Comment: I think he wants to zoom in particular parts, not the whole screen.

Comment: correct ... im looking to use the scroll wheel to drive a "zoom into this part" .. and then a scroll wheel the other way to zoom out .. and scroll wheel up to zoom in again

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at the http://html5readiness.com/ source code. You can do exactly that in the center portion.

This is copied from Paul Irish HTML5Readiness website :

```
jQuery(document).bind('DOMMouseScroll mousewheel', function(e, delta) {

  var newval,
      num = $('div.css-chart p').css('padding-left');

  delta = delta || e.detail || e.wheelDelta;

  if (delta > 0 || e.which == 38) {
      newval = parseFloat(num) + 10 * (e.shiftKey ? .1 : 1);
  } else if (delta < 0 || e.which == 40) {
      newval = parseFloat(num) - 10 * (e.shiftKey ? .1 : 1);
  } else {
      return true;
  }

  $('style.padleft').remove();
  $('<style class="padleft"> div.css-chart p { padding-left : '+newval+'px; } div.css-chart p i { width : '+2*newval+'px; } </style>')
      .appendTo(document.body);

  e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: Just to add to this, if you're happy to rely on CSS3, a very easy solution is to adjust `transform: scale(x.x)` ([MDN page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/Using_CSS_transforms)) on the container element you want to zoom when the scrollwheel event fires.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is Zoom.js (http://lab.hakim.se/zoom-js/) which zooms in on a specified element, or Presenteer.js (http://willemmulder.github.com/Presenteer.js/) which can center specified elements in the viewport and also takes CSS3 transforms (e.g. rotation, translate) of these elements into account.